# grab data from .plist ios in PHP

Tags: php, ios, xml, plist

so this is the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>New item</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://down.weapp.com/apps/zb/002/43/12/21/58cae8840ba0628e304b1118.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/57x57bb.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://www.weapp.com/picture/app_ios/cn/002/43/12/21/512x512bb.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.xiaoji.gamecenter</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.5.2</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>小鸡模拟器</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and i want to grab the .ipa url, to do this i am using simplexml

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($plistString)
```

now i would access it doing

```
$xmlPlist->dict->array[0]->string,
```

but there are 2 strings there, how can i access the url one?
now this is confusing for me, am i even accessing the plis in the correct way? should i mention every "dict" there is?

Comment: You can either iterate through the entries in the dict until you find a `key` matching `url` and then take the next `string`, or you could use `xpath`.

Comment: i am not that advanced, can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $xml->dict->array->dict->array->dict->string[1];
```

Comment: no funciona :( te importa si hablamos por otro sitio? lo necesito

Comment: null, por eso creo que el problema esta en otro sitio, contactame sin darte de alta aqui tlk.io/problemadelplist

Answer (score 0):

To search XML, you should use XPath. This code should do the trick:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($plistString);
$result = $xml->xpath('//dict[./key/text()="kind" and ./string/text()="software-package"]/key[text()="url"]/following-sibling::string');
$url = (string)$result[0];
```

---

So what's that mean? First:

```
dict[./key/text()="kind" and ./string/text()="software-package"]
```

We compare [child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8981091/1255289) and their [text content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033955/1255289); we're looking for a `<dict>` that contains `<key>kind</key>` and `<string>software-package</string>`.

Then:

```
/key[text()="url"]/following-sibling::string
```

We take that `<dict>` element, and look for a child `<key>` element with "url" as it's text content, and get the `<string>` element [following it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11657223/1255289).

We still have an XML element at that point, so we use [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to get it to a string.